# How to stream video on android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

Beside VideoView, are there other ways to stream videos in my android app? I need a customized solution so my question is not talking about implicit intents. I mean within android itself, for API 14, is VideoView the only way to stream a video in my app. Thanks.

Comment: Do you try `Exoplayer` ?

Comment: Is your concern with the *streaming* or *presentation* of the video? What is it about VideoView that isn't working for you? (It's hard to suggest an alternative when you haven't explained why the built-in stuff doesn't do what you need.)

Comment: Exoplayer requires api 16. As for streaming vs presentation: streaming more smoothly perhaps especially on poor network connections.